# extJS portal issue

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am using this for my current application http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/portal/portal.html. I tried to replace the current chart (in the third column) with a bar and a pie chart (that are working if in panels and windows) , but got "h is undefined" error in the console. I have confirmed each line of code of charts several time to find out any mistake but there is none. Please guide me.....Your help is deeply appreciated. 
My chartportlet requires this "requires:["Ext.data.JsonStore","Ext.chart.*","Ext.layout.container.Fit"]"

Here is my code for chartportlet (third column)

```
   xtype: 'chart',
        id: 'chartCmp',
        animate: true,
        store: Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
    fields: ['year', 'comedy', 'action', 'drama', 'thriller'],
    data: [
            {year: 2005,  action: 23890000},
            {year: 2006,  action: 38900000},
            {year: 2007,  action: 50410000},
            {year: 2008,  action: 56070000}
          ]
}),
        shadow: true,
        legend: {
            position: 'right'
        },
        insetPadding: 60,
        theme: 'Base:gradients',
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            field: 'action',
            showInLegend: true,
            donut: false,

            highlight: {
              segment: {
                margin: 20
              }
            },
            label: {
                field: 'year',
                display: 'rotate',
                contrast: true,
                font: '18px Arial'
            }
        }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't develop using minimized ExtJS files. Use the debug versions and you will get much more sensible error messages than "h is undefined".

Comment: So... investigate from which file and function does this error come from.

Comment: ext-core.js, this is the file

Comment: So launch your debugger and see where the error happens in ext-core.